# Difference between Vaadin getContent.addComponent() and addComponent()?

Tags: java, vaadin

If I extend a component like Form in Vaadin, would be any difference between those two?

```
1. this.getContent().addComponent();

2. this.addComponent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no getContent() method in [Form](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Form.html) class

If you mean [Panel.getContent](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Panel.html#getContent%28%29) method then there is no difference between those two methods.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! You're right about the Form class, it is only the panel class then :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between `this.getContent().addComponent();` and `this.addComponent();`  when you consider [Window](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html) and [Panel](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Panel.html) components. The component gets added to the content with either call. In [Form](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.form.html) however, there is no method such as `addComponent()`.